# Got gulp instead of grunt in a project created using angular-fullstack

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack, yo

I have created an App using angular-fullstack generator , for my previous projects i got grunt upon creation of the app ; But for this project i got gulp instead of grunt. I followed the same procedure like i did for my previous apps. Did yeoman replace grunt with gulp in the recent time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yeoman generator (generator-angular-fullstack) has been updated to use Gulp (and lots of other changes).  The git repository for it has a good changelog - I am sure you can go back to an older version.